# When Selenium Webdriver login to third party application asking for verification code

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have not come across this issue before.  I have a web application for which I have to create 'step 1' using third party application. Step 1 has to be created by logging into their application first.  When I do that manually I do not get a verification screen in which the third party application sends number keys to my email id.  When my Webdriver script tries to login, it asks for the code. What's the resolution for this problem?  Is there a solution?

Thank you